# Tank auth to use md5

Tags: codeigniter, authorization, md5

I am working on a registration system for a 3rd party server, and (though tank auth's hashing is great), I need an md5 (so the third party software can check against it).
Is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks,
Max

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do it the right way, you would write your own hash functions to use in Tank_Auth and remove the current ones.

If you *don't* want to do it the right way, Tank_Auth uses the included [phpass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) `PasswordHash` class to hash and validate passwords. Only two functions are called from the Tank_Auth library: `CheckPassword` and `HashPassword`. Make a backup, and rewrite these two functions to use `md5()` instead. You may simply ignore the configuration and other `PasswordHash` methods.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a built in md5 hashing function ( md5() ), although I'd recommend sha1 ( sha1() ) over md5.

edit: ah, you're required to use an md5 hash is what you're saying? then just md5()

Comment: Is there an easy way to incorporate this into tank auth?